# Bootstrap get value of both two dropdownlist at a time

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using two bootstrap dropdownlist. I want to get value of both dropdownlist at a time.

My html,

```
<div class="btn-group  col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-md-5 cgclry country" style="padding:3px 3px;"> 
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="border:0;">All Country<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu countries">
        <li><a href="#" data-id="USA" id="usa">USA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Australia" id="aus">Australia</a></li>
        <li ><a href="#" data-id="INDIA" id="ind">INDIA</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group col-sm-5  col-xs-5 col-md-5 " style="padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;"> 
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select"    data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="border:none;">All Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu category">
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Tom Tailer" id="Tom Tailer">Tom Tailer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Pepe Jeans" id="Pepe Jeans">Pepe Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Sinet Tech" id="Sinet Tech">Sinet Tech</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="others" id="others"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Other</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My jquery,

```
$(document).on('click','.countries li a',function(){
    c=$(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(c);
});

 $(document).on('click','.category li a',function(){
    c=$(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(c);
 });
```

for example, I am click india in country dropdown list and then click Tom tailer in category list. i want the result india as well as Tom tailer.

Comment: didn't got your problem

Comment: Me neither. What do you mean by simultaneously? What is the current behaviour and what would you instead expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I understood the question to be asking for one function to get values from either list with the same code.

My implementation (improvements welcome):
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpJvXx

```
$(document).ready( function () {

  var getListAttributes = function (selector) {
    listValue = selector.attr('data-value');
    alert(listValue);
  }

  $(document).on('click','.js-select a', function() {
      getListAttributes($(this));
   });
});
```

Comment: for example, I am click india in country dropdown list and then click Tom tailer in category list. i want the result india as well as Tom tailer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this implementation might be more what you are looking for:

http://codepen.io/Aaron-AF/pen/qOdgBm

```
$(document).ready( function () {
var listValues = [];
  var setDropDownResults = function (selector) {
    if(listValues.length < 1) {
      $('.js-category').removeClass('hidden');
      $('.js-select-country').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
      $('.js-select-category').prop('disabled', true);
    }
    listValues.push(" " + selector.val());
    $('.js-results').text("Results: " + listValues);
  };
  var resetDropDown = function () {
    listValues = [];
    $('.js-category').addClass('hidden');
    $('.js-select-country, .js-select-category').prop('disabled', false);
    $('.js-results').text('');
  };

  $('select').change(function() {
      setDropDownResults($(this));
   });
  $('.js-reset').click( function() {
    resetDropDown();
  });

});
```

It should provide you, at the least, with a base that will allow you to complete what you wish to do.

Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

## [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/qhEvUiiQXd)

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group  col-sm-5 col-xs-5 col-md-5 cgclry country" style="padding:3px 3px;"> 
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select2" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="border:0;">All Country<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu countries">
        <li><a class="first" href="#" data-id="USA" id="usa">USA</a></li>
        <li><a class="first" href="#" data-id="Australia" id="aus">Australia</a></li>
        <li><a class="first" href="#" data-id="INDIA" id="ind">INDIA</a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="btn-group col-sm-5  col-xs-5 col-md-5 " style="padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;"> 
    <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle btn-select" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="border:none;">All Category<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu category">
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Tom Tailer" id="Tom Tailer">Tom Tailer</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Pepe Jeans" id="Pepe Jeans">Pepe Jeans</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="Sinet Tech" id="Sinet Tech">Sinet Tech</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="others" id="others"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Other</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click','.countries li a',function(){
    c=$(this).attr('data-id');
   $('.first').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
    alert(c);
});

 $(document).on('click','.category li a',function(){
    c=$(this).attr('data-id');
   b=$('.active').attr('data-id');
    alert(c +' '+ b);

 });
```